# Merge passed function parameter with default parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

What's the most efficient way to merge a default function parameter as of the latest versions of JavaScript?

What I would like to achieve:

```
var defaultParam = {a: 1};

function foo(param = defaultParam) {
   // desired result : param = {a: 1, b: 2}
}

var passedParam = {b: 2};
foo(passedParam);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use that inside the function and not as a default param for the function. Because the way you expect, whenever you send a value to the function it will overwrite the default value so the better approach is to get that object prepared for the function param inside the function.

```js
var defaultParam = {a: 1};

function foo(param) {
   let newParam = {
     ...defaultParam,
     ...param
   }
   console.log(newParam);
}

var passedParam = {b: 2};
foo(passedParam)
```

In that case, you can even take `var defaultParam` inside the function or use it directly as:

```
function foo(param) {
   let newParam= {
     a: 1,
     ...param
   }
   console.log(newParam);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new object on the first line of the function instead, putting in the default values, and then overwriting its properties with the properties in the passed object (if any):

```js
var defaultParam = {a: 1};

function foo(param) {
    const cleanParam = { ...defaultParam, ...param };
    console.log(cleanParam);
}

var passedParam = {b: 2};
foo(passedParam)
```